# C++ Passing a dynamicly allocated 2D array by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, multidimensional-array

This question builds off of a previously asked question:
[Pass by reference multidimensional array with known size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529109/c-pass-by-reference-multidimensional-array-with-known-size)

I have been trying to figure out how to get my functions to play nicely with 2d array references.  A simplified version of my code is:

```
    unsigned int ** initialize_BMP_array(int height, int width)
    {
       unsigned int ** bmparray;
       bmparray = (unsigned int **)malloc(height * sizeof(unsigned int *));
       for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
       {
        bmparray[i] = (unsigned int *)malloc(width * sizeof(unsigned int));
       }
      for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
             bmparray[i][j] = 0;
        }
    return bmparray;
    }
```

I don't know how I can re-write this function so that it will work where I pass bmparray in as an empty unsigned int ** by reference so that I could allocate the space for the array in one function, and set the values in another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a class to wrap it, then pass objects by reference

```
class BMP_array
{
public:
    BMP_array(int height, int width)
    : buffer(NULL)
    {
       buffer = (unsigned int **)malloc(height * sizeof(unsigned int *));
       for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
       {
        buffer[i] = (unsigned int *)malloc(width * sizeof(unsigned int));
       }

    }

    ~BMP_array()
    {
        // TODO: free() each buffer
    }

    unsigned int ** data()
    {
        return buffer;
    }

private:
// TODO: Hide or implement copy constructor and operator=
unsigned int ** buffer
};
```

Comment: This seems like a lot of boiler plate just to pass an array.  If he only ever works with the raw data, why wrap it in a class?

Comment: It depends how many different operations are made on the data, but my opinion is that, even just for the initialize operation and the memory management, it's worth using a class.

Comment: I agree. There's no way I would allocate a resource without wrapping it somehow.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what the question was.  The question was syntactical - how to pass an array.  That's not the same as whether you should pass an array.  And I can think of cases where you would want to pass a raw array.

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef array_type unsigned int **;
initialize_BMP_array(array_type& bmparray, int height, int width)
```

Answer (score 2):

Mmm... maybe I don't understand well your question, but in C you can pass "by reference" by passing another pointer indirection level. That is, a pointer to the double pointer bmparray itself:

```
unsigned int ** initialize_BMP_array(int height, int width, unsigned int *** bmparray)
{
   /* Note the first asterisk */
   *bmparray = (unsigned int **)malloc(height * sizeof(unsigned int *));

   ...

   the rest is the same but with a level of indirection


   return *bmparray;
}
```

So the memory for the bmparray is reserved inside the function (and then, passed by reference).

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if I have a function,I am allocating some memory using malloc and a pointer,actually I am extending an array. Now I have to pass the same array using return.Now I cannot even free that before I return.What can I do in this case?

Comment: You have to write that two functions so that the function that receives the allocated array frees it afterwards. That is, the function that receives the allocated value has to know that it has to free it.

Answer (score 1):

To use the safer and more modern C++ idiom, you should be using vectors rather than dynamically allocated arrays.

```
void initialize_BMP_array(vector<vector<unsigned int> > &bmparray, int height, int width);
```