# Allocate a dynamic 2d-array by passing it to another function by reference

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic, pass-by-reference

This question builds off of two previously asked questions: [C++ Passing a dynamicly allocated 2D array by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529875/c-passing-a-dynamicly-allocated-2d-array-by-reference) & [C - Pass by reference multidimensional array with known size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529109/c-pass-by-reference-multidimensional-array-with-known-size)

I was trying to allocate memory for a 2d-Array using the answers of these previous questions, but the memory never been allocated and I receive a BAD_ACCESS error every time a try to access the array!

This is what I have:

```
const int rows = 10;
const int columns = 5;

void allocate_memory(char *** maze); //prototype

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  char ** arr;
  allocate_memory(&arr) //pass by reference to allocate memory
  return 0;
}

void allocate_memory(char *** maze) {
  int i;
  maze =  malloc(sizeof(char *) * rows);
  for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
      maze[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * columns);
}
```

Comment: Small point: why are you using `10` for the `malloc` call when you have defined `rows` which you use immediately after?

Comment: Please don't try to be a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer). Other than that technically C doesn't have "pass by reference", you can only *emulate* it.

Comment: Was a typo, I already fixed it. Thanks for notifying

Comment: As for your problem, in the function you have a pointer to the pointer to the pointer. The first indirection is because you passed a pointer to the variable, but that's only local inside your function. Have you ever wondered about the *dereference* operator `*` sometimes, and when to use it? Now might be a good idea to read up about it.

Comment: Note that `maze =  malloc(sizeof(char *) * 10);` will only change the local copy passed to it. It won't affect the pointer you passed, which remains uninitialised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should note that there is no *pass by reference* in C, only *pass by value*.

Now, you need to allocate memory for `maze[0]` (or `*maze`)

```
*maze =  malloc(sizeof(char *) * rows);
```

and then

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
  (*maze)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * columns);
```

Comment: can I use `*maze` instead of `maze[0]`? is it the same?

Comment: @Insty1956 yes, remember to write `(*maze)` though when using `[]` after

Comment: @Insty1956; Yes. You can.

Comment: so I just have to change my both allocation to the following? `*maze =  malloc(sizeof(char *) * rows);  ` `*maze[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * columns);`. THAT'S IT?

Comment: `*maze[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * columns);` should be `(*maze)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * columns);`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Maybe you can also change the signature to `char **allocate_memory(int rows, int columns)`.